# How do I use two models on a shared layout page in MVC 3 ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model

I have a main layout page that has a basic table setup.  I have a Main Content cell that I use to put RenderBody() in.  I have product listings that use a Products database and I have a menu on the right side that needs to access the User database.  How can I list my products using the products model in the Main Content cell and use the users model to list info in my Menu cell?

Comment: Without some code sample your question is kinda abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only method I have used (however I'm not entirely confident on it's best practice status) is to create a model for the page that includes both (in your case) the `product` model and the `user` model. Populate these models in the controller, then access the inner models as you normally would in the view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use partials to render content sections.

Imagine your page uses this model:

```
public class PageModel {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ProductListModel Products { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can render your partial view and pass in the model for that:

```
@Html.Partial( "name of partial view", Model.Products )
```

A slightly more performance costly approach is to call an action to render the partial view:

```
public class ProductsController {
    public ActionResult List() {
        var model = new ProductListModel();
        return View( "your partial view", model );
    }
}
```

And in your view:

```
@Html.Action( "list", "products" )
```

The advantage of the latter approach is that you keep your page model relatively clean, so that it doesn't have to contain all the data needed to display the page.